# CocoaPods installation error: WARNING: CocoaPods is not installed or is not configured properly

Tags: angular, xcode, cocoapods, nativescript, mobile-development

I'm trying to do env setup for native script: https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios

After running sudo ns doctor ios, I'm getting below error:

✔ Getting environment information

There seem to be issues with your configuration.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.5.3 version and is up to date.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 14.3.1 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✖ WARNING: CocoaPods is not installed or is not configured properly.
You will not be able to build your projects for iOS if they contain plugin with CocoaPod file.
To be able to build such projects, verify that you have installed CocoaPods (`sudo gem install cocoapods`).

Your environment is not configured properly and you will not be able to execute local builds.
Verify that your environment is configured according to the system requirements described at
https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios.

I can see pod version after running this:
pod --version
1.12.1

Does anyone has any idea, how to resolve this.